# Trouble with glVertexArrayVertexBuffer() / glVertexArrayAttribFormat() in different buffer layouts

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

I'm trying to bring my OpenGL code up to speed with Direct State access and have been closely following the code from [Guide to Modern OpenGL Functions](https://github.com/fendevel/Guide-to-Modern-OpenGL-Functions#glbuffer). I have a little test project with some vertices and colors in the form of:

```
std::vector<float> vertices;
for (float y = -1.0f; y < 1.1f; y += 1.0f) {
    for (float x = -1.0f; x < 1.1f; x += 1.0f) {
        vertices.emplace_back(x);
        vertices.emplace_back(y);
        vertices.emplace_back(0.5f);
        vertices.emplace_back(0.5f);
        vertices.emplace_back(0.5f);
    }
}
```

A visual representation of those vertices and their indices:

[image]

My main draw code is something like this:

```
unsigned int vbo = 0;
glCreateBuffers(1, &vbo);
glNamedBufferStorage(vbo, sizeof(float) * vertices.size(), vertices.data(), GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

// Indices
unsigned int indices[]{ 0,1,3,5,8,7 };
unsigned int ibo = 0;
glCreateBuffers(1, &ibo);
glNamedBufferStorage(ibo, sizeof(unsigned int) * 6, indices, GL_DYNAMIC_STORAGE_BIT);

int bindingindex_a = 1;
int bindingindex_b = 2;
int pos_location = 3;
int color_location = 4;

unsigned int vao = 0;
glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_a, vbo, 0, 5 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_b, vbo, 0, 5 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayElementBuffer(vao, ibo);

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, pos_location);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, color_location);

glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, pos_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, color_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2*sizeof(float));

glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, pos_location, bindingindex_a);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, color_location, bindingindex_b);
```

So I'm drawing two gray triangles with the indices 0,1,3 and 5,8,7. Attribute locations in my shader are specified as in the cpp code:

```
layout (location = 3) in vec2 pos;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 col;
```

And this works!:

[image]

Even when I increase the difficulty and add a single float value in front, I can adjust the offset in the `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer()` function by 4 bytes.

The problem is when I want to go from buffer layout A to B:

[image]

I adjust my data filling loop to first write the positions, then the colors:

```
for (float y = -1.0f; y < 1.1f; y += 1.0f) {
    for (float x = -1.0f; x < 1.1f; x += 1.0f) {
        vertices.emplace_back(x);
        vertices.emplace_back(y);
    }
}
for (float y = -1.0f; y < 1.1f; y += 1.0f) {
    for (float x = -1.0f; x < 1.1f; x += 1.0f) {
        vertices.emplace_back(0.5f);
        vertices.emplace_back(0.5f);
        vertices.emplace_back(0.5f);
    }
}
```

and adjust the calls to `glVertexArrayVertexBuffer()` and `glVertexArrayAttribFormat()`:

```
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_a, vbo, 0, 2 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_b, vbo, 18*sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));

glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, pos_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, color_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
```

So now my global color offset is at 18 floats (9 positions times two components) and my `relativeoffset` (that's how [khronos.org](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribFormat.xhtml) calls it) is at 0 for both. This displays grey things, but not the way they did before. My mental model of how these things work is obviously wrong - where?

Comment: "*The problem is when I want to go from buffer layout A to B:*" You should not want to do that. If you care about performance, don't change vertex formats.

Comment: Is abcabc faster than aaabbbccc?

Comment: Generally yes, but my point was more about switching between them with any frequency. And you *certainly* shouldn't be switching between them by modifing the VAO; you should have one interleaved VAO and one non-interleaved VAO.

Comment: Oh sure, I know that. I merely included example A to show that my code has no fundamental other problem and that I have a rough understanding. I have no intention of changing anything during runtime. But thanks! I didn't know about the perf difference though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *offset* parameter of [`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) is the offset of the first element of the buffer in bytes, form the begin of the buffer and *stride* is distance between consecutive attributes within the buffer.

---

The vertex specification for case A is wrong:

> ```cpp
> glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_a, vbo, 0, 5 * sizeof(float));
> glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_b, vbo, 0, 5 * sizeof(float));
> ```

Each vertex attribute tuple consists of 5 components (x, y, r, g, b).

```
(x1, y1, r1, g1, b1,   x2, y2, r2, g2, b2,   x3, y3, r3, g3, b3, ...)
```

Hence the offset for the color attribute is `2*sizeof(float)`:

```cpp
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_a, vbo, 0, 5 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_b, vbo, 2 * sizeof(float), 5 * sizeof(float));
```

The byte offset of *x1* is `0`.
The byte offset of *r1* is `2 * sizeof(float)`.
The distance in bytes from *x1* to *x2* is `5 * sizeof(float)`.
The distance in bytes form *r1* to *r2* is `5 * sizeof(float)`.

---

The offset for case B is correct:

> ```cpp
> glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_a, vbo, 0, 2 * sizeof(float));
> glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_b, vbo, 18*sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));
> ```

In case B there are 9 vertex coordinates, followed by 3 color attributes. A vertex tuple has w components and a color tuple has 3 components:

```
(x1, y1, x2, y2, ... x9, y9,  r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2, ..., r9, g9, b9)
```

Hence the offset of the start of the color attribute is `9*sizeof(float)` (3 * (x, y)):

```cpp
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_a, vbo, 0, 2 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, bindingindex_b, vbo, 18 * sizeof(float), 3 * sizeof(float));
```

The byte offset of *x1* is `0`.
The byte offset of *r1* is `18 * sizeof(float)`.
The distance in bytes form *x1* to *x2* is `2 * sizeof(float)`.
The distance in bytes from *r1* to *r2* is `3 * sizeof(float)`.

Comment: Huh.. the first I can get to work, but only with 0 for the relativeoffset parameter of glVertexArrayAttribFormat(). The second has wrong colors with the 0 for relativeoffset. Or what would those values be?

Comment: "but only with 0 for the relativeoffset parameter" - but that is completely wrong. Case B is correct. _offset_ is the offset of the first element of the buffer and stride is _distance_ between consecutive attributes within the buffer. I've extended the answer.